# How to get list of unique objects with their number from the List<Object>

Tags: dart

I nave list of objects , e.g.

```
List<Product> products = [product1, product2, product1, product2, product1, product1]
```

How I can to get list of unique objects with  their number from the List?

```
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';

part 'product.g.dart';

abstract class Product implements Built<Product, ProductBuilder>{
  int get id;
  String get title;
  String get image;
  double get price;
  int get volume;

  static Serializer<Product> get serializer => _$productSerializer;
  Product._();
  factory Product([updates(ProductBuilder b)]) = _$Product;
}
```

I would like to get other List with objects:

```
class OrderPosition {
int id;
String title;
int count; // number of unique elements from list 'products'
}
```

For example:

```
List<OrderPosition> = [
OrderPosition(1, title1, 4),
OrderPosition(2, title2, 2)
]
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at `Set<E>` which is basically a list of unique objects https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Set-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Map<int, OrderPosition> _positionList = Map(); //map for orders (unique products and heir number)

  List<Product> _orderList = [p1, p1, p2, p1, p3, p3, p2]; // list of products
..........
//
  void addPosition(Product product) {
    var uniqueProducts = _orderList.toSet().toList();
    for(int i = 0; i < uniqueProducts.length; i++){
      var value = OrderPosition(
          uniqueProducts[i].title,
          getCount(uniqueProducts[i].id));
      _positionList[uniqueProducts[i].id] = value;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
class Product {
  Product(this.id); // for operator == to work properly
  final int id;     // make at least the id immutable

  String title;
  String image;
  double price;
  int volume;

  bool operator ==(Object other) => identical(this, other) || (other as Product).id == id;

  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

```
var uniqueProducts = products.toSet().toList();
var result = <OrderPosition>[];
for(var i = 0; i < uniqueProducts.length; i++) {
  result.add(
    OrderPosition(i, 
                  uniqueProducts[i].title, 
                  products.where((e) => e == uniqueProducts[i]).length)));
}
```

Comment: The `identical(this, other)` makes the rest of the test unnecessary. Did you mean `||`? If so, you probably still need `other is Product && id == other.id` to handle non-`Product` arguments.

Comment: My class Product is abstract, I changed it in question

Comment: Thanks for the great solution! More info on this topic can be found in their docs at https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#implementing-map-keys

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative, using `Set.putIfAbsent`, is to collect the information in one iteration:

```
var uniqueProductMap = Map<Product, OrderPosition>.identity();
for (var product in products) {
  var position = uniqueProductMap.putIfAbsent(product, 
     () => OrderPosition(product.id, product.title, 0);
  position.count++;
}
var uniqueProducts = uniqueProductMap.values.toList();
```

This uses `identical` for deciding which elements are unique. If you want to use equality instead, replace the map with just `<Product, OrderPosition>{}`. If you want to use another equivalence not supported by the object itself, you can use:

```
var uniqueProductMap = LinkedHashMap<Product, OrderPosition>(
    equals: (p1, p2) => p1.id == p2.id,
    hashCode: (p) => p.id.hashCode);
```

(I fully support the recommendation to make `id` final if you use it for equality comparisons).